# is is possible to generate examples from PolymorphicProxySerializer using drf-spectacular

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

I am using `drf-spectacular` to generate some swagger documentations. There is one endpoints, that supports multiple body requests and I am using `PolymorphicProxySerializer` to describe this `oneOf` schema. Also, I see that by default one example is auto generated for one of the serializers. I was wondering if it is possible to also have second example for second serializer, that is automatically generated.

This is my schema:

```
    @extend_schema(
        request=PolymorphicProxySerializer(
            "PatchDifferentProducts",
            serializers=[create_update_single_product_serializer, create_update_portfolio_product_serializer],
            resource_type_field_name=None,
        ),
        responses={status.HTTP_200_OK: ""},
    )
```

I want dropdown for both serializers, so I can have example value for both of them.
[image]

Could not find anything related to this in docs.